Accessing domain/auth/google/callback I get blank screen, and 404 on the resources
I'm using Nginx and Traefik for the React Vite app,
And I have a route defined as fellow:
<Route path="auth/google/callback" element={<GoogleAuthCallback />} />
When accessing the route in localhost works as expected, but using it in the production results in a blank screen where the index.html is correctly served to auth/google/callback but the resources are not loaded because the path is not correct as you can see in the image

Note: only this path doesn't work accessing other paths works well.
Here are my Traefik logs when calling the endpoint
"GET /auth/google/callback?state=eyJhbGciO.....&authuser=0&prompt=none HTTP/2.0" 200 466 "-" "-" 18327 "websecure-....-eu@kubernetes" "http://10.224.0.121:8080" 0m
here is my Nginx client configuration:
`    location ~* .(?:manifest|config|appcache|html?|xml|json)$ {
expires -1;
}
location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
  try_files $uri =404;
  expires 1y;
  access_log off;
  add_header Cache-Control "public";
}

location ~* \.(?:png|jpe?g|svg|ttf|ico|woff2|woff)$ {
  try_files $uri =404;
  expires 1y;
  access_log off;
  add_header Cache-Control "public";
}

# Any route containing a file extension (e.g. /devicesfile.js)
location ~ ^.+\..+$ {
  try_files $uri =404;
}

# Any route that doesn't have a file extension (e.g. /devices)
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}`

I tried modifying the Nginx config, but no luck! I also tried to use HashedRoute but had no luck with this endpoint.
